# R Function for creating batch hypothesis testing

Tags: r

Suppose I have many variables and I wish to run the hypothesis testing for each category of each variable. The data df looks like this

```
ID    Score    Gender    Hobby     Vegan_status      X1     ....   Xn
1      30        F       Tennis         Yes
2      28        F       Swimming       Yes
3      27        M       Reading        No
4      29        M       Tennis         Yes
5      28        M       Reading        Yes
6      24        M       Reading        Yes
7      18        M       Baseball       No
8      15        F       Shopping       No
```

I wish to test the hypothesis that the Score of each gender under certain categorical variable, for example, for Tennis:

```
 wilcox.test(df$Score[df$Gender=="F" & df$Hobby=="Tennis"],
            df$Score[df$Gender=="M" & df$Hobby=="Tennis"])
```

so here I am testing the difference in Score for individuals of different gender with hobby Tennis.
Likewise, for Reading:

```
wilcox.test(df$Score[df$Gender=="F" & df$Hobby=="Reading"],
        df$Score[df$Gender=="M" & df$Hobby=="Reading"])
```

and for different categorical variable, say Vegan_status:

```
wilcox.test(df$Score[df$Gender=="F" & df$Vegan_status=="Yes"],
        df$Score[df$Gender=="M" & df$Vegan_status=="Yes"])
```

and

```
wilcox.test(df$Score[df$Gender=="F" & df$Vegan_status=="No"],
        df$Score[df$Gender=="M" & df$Vegan_status=="No"])
```

This part is fixed (Score and Gender) but how do I write a function so I don't have to enter each categorical variable manually since there are more than a hundred of variables.

```
 wilcox.test(df$Score[df$Gender=="F" & df$X],
        df$Score[df$Gender=="M" & df$X])
```

Comment: It might be worth considering a regression approach as opposed to testing all of your predictor variables separately. Have you ruled this out for any particular reason?

Comment: Yeah, the model performance is not looking great. So I am running tests instead of the regression model.

Comment: It might first be worth revisiting your modeling approach to make sure it's valid. Also, if a method is used like the one in your post, the p-values definitely need to be corrected for multiple comparisons to avoid getting into p-hacking territory.

Comment: Yeah. I see what you meant.The goal is to find out which category has a higher or lower Score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` with formula version of `wilcox.test`:

```
by(df, df$Hobby, function(sub)     
    wilcox.test(Score ~ Gender, data=sub) 
)
```

Should you need a matrix return, extract needed estimates and bind list results:

```
results_list <- by(df, df$Hobby, function(sub){
                     res <- wilcox.test(Score ~ Gender, data=sub) 
    
                     return(c(statistic = unname(res$statistic), 
                              p_value = res$p.value))
                 })
    
    
results_matrix <- do.call(rbind, results_list)
    
results_matrix
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/SMRJL45236)</kbd>

Comment: So with by function it generated new subsets based on the Hobby for each category. Thank you very much! This is precisely what I want.

Comment: Great to hear! If you do not need to call a function (third arg of `by`), consider, `split` that returns a list of data frames subsetted by one or more factor(s): `split(df, df$Hobby)`. Just don't do `split` + `for/lapply` loop since `by` handles both in one call.